# Swiftui warning Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior

Tags: swiftui

When I run my swiftui app I am getting the following warning **runtime: SwiftUI: Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.** . I get that warning implementing Map and I know why I am getting it . Is there a way to fix the issue so that I do not get that warning . I basically initialize the MKCoordinateRegion then I have a function with a closure that gets the latitude and longitude and I update the MKCoordinateRegion . I call this method inside onappear

```
 PlaceViewModel().CreatedBy(PlaceID) { x in

     showMap = true
     region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: x?.latitude ?? 0.0, longitude: x?.longitude ?? 0.0), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)) // warning comes here
            }
```

rest of code , any suggestions on getting rid of that warning would be great

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct PlaceView: View {

    @State  var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @State var mainModel = [MainModel]()
    @State var model = PlaceModel()
    @State var mainModelValue = MainModelValue()
    @Binding var PlaceID: Int
    @State var IsMainView = MainViewEnum(viewType: .PlaceView)
    @State var triggerView = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var ProfileState = false
    @State var showMap = false
    

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack
            {
                
                Color(UIColor(hexString: "#E0EAEA"))
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            HStack {
                Image("back-arrow")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                Text(model.Name ?? "Places")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
             }.padding(0)
            }.frame(height: 35)
          
            if showMap == true {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: .constant(.follow))
                    .frame(height: 152)
            }
           
            HStack {
                Text("Added By: ")
                
                Text(model.createdby ?? "")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        ProfileState.toggle()
                    }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $ProfileState,content: {
                        ProfileHeaderView(Name: model.fullname ?? "", UserID: model.userid ?? 0)
                    })
            }.padding([.top], 15)
            if triggerView == true {
                TimeLineView(model: mainModel, isMainView: $IsMainView, newValue: mainModelValue,UserID: MYID)
                    .padding(.top,0)
            }
            
        }.padding(0)
        .onAppear {
            IsMainView.PlaceID = PlaceID
            triggerView = true
            
            PlaceViewModel().CreatedBy(PlaceID) { x in
                showMap = true
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: x?.latitude ?? 0.0, longitude: x?.longitude ?? 0.0), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)) // The warning happens here
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct PlaceView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PlaceView(PlaceID: .constant(0))
    }
}
```

You can reproduce the issue with this .

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct TesterView: View {
    @State var PlaceID: Int?
    @State var isTapped = false
    var body: some View {

          VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
           Text("test")
        .onTapGesture {
            isTapped.toggle()
            }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isTapped,content: {
                ReproduceView(PlaceID: $PlaceID)
             })
          }
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TesterView()
    }
}

}


struct ReproduceView: View {

    @State  var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @State var showMap = false
    @Binding var PlaceID: Int?

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 0) {
         
          
            if showMap == true {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: .constant(.follow))
                    .frame(height: 152)
            }
           
          
            
        }.padding(0)
        .onAppear {
           showMap = true
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.7490, longitude: -84.3880), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct Reproduce_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReproduceView(PlaceID: .constant(0))
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty hard to say what's going on without at least showing code for `PlaceViewModel`. Can you create a [mre] without all of the extraneous custom types so that someone can try the code?

Comment: Yes I just updated the example above and put in the code to reproduce the issue .

Comment: Not seeing that error when running your sample code.